# Is it possible to add a spinner to a tab in android actionbar?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, spinner

I have an actionbar which contains three `tabs`, I'm looking into adding a spinner to each of the tabs for a simpler UI.

All examples I've seen so far only show how to add a spinner to an actionbar but not to the tabs. It looks like the examples i've seen so far replaces the tabs with a spinner. Thats not what i want. I want a spinner to be activated when a tab is pressed. Or can i replace the tabs with several spinners?

Is this possible? Can anyone point me in a direction.

Comment: why don't you try it before asking?

Comment: Well i've tried, been banging my head for a while with the Android UI. But i'm gonna look into the link posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a spinner in the actionbar. Check the link below:

[Adding Spinner Drop-down to Action bar](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, If you are looking for NavigationTab, which is part of actionBar , take a look here- [how to add navigation-tabs in actionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs). You need to implement custom adapter for the tab to integrate [spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) inside navigation tab.

Look this links this will help you:

1. [actionbar sherlock tabs with spinner and .setOnItemSelectedListener(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945504/actionbar-sherlock-tabs-with-spinner-and-setonitemselectedlistenerthis)
2. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown
3. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html
4. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/
5. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html